# How can I send snmp trap from freebsd

Tags: freebsd, snmp

I'm on Freebsd 12. I installed NET-SNMP version 5.7.3 on my system.  The problem is in sending traps. For example the link up/down does not sending trap. The config files are:

snmpd.conf

```
view   V  included   .1
view   V  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.1
view   V  included   .1.3.6.1.2.1.25.1
view   V  included   .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.3
view   V  included   .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4
rocommunity public 

trapcommunity public
trap2sink   localhost public

defaultMonitors          yes
linkUpDownNotifications  yes
```

snmptrapd.conf

```
format  print1  %.4y-%.2m-%.2l  %.2h:%.2j:%.2k  %B  [%b] (via %A [%a]):     %N\n\t%W Trap (%q) Uptime: %#T\n%v\n

format print2 %.4y-%.2m-%.2l %.2h:%.2j:%.2k %B [%b]:\n%v\n

disableAuthorization yes
```

sockstat -4 -l

```
root     snmptrapd  635   9  udp4   *:162                 *:*
root     snmpd      540   10 udp4   *:161                 *:*
```

I check the packets on wireshark, but I don't  receive any packet from snmp.

Thanks for your attention. I'm looking forward to your reply.

Comment: Great using wireshark. I see no obvious issue. To narrow it further down try using [snmptrap](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=snmptrap) to send a manual trap. Does that show on the network?

Comment: @ Claus Andersen I send this trap: `sudo snmptrap -v 2c -c public A.B.C.D:162 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4 .1.3.6.1.6.3.1.1.5.4  ifIndex i 5 ifAdminStatus i 1 ifOperStatus i 1` . but nothing had happen!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is:

Adding two commands in `snmpd.conf`

```
monitor  -r 1s -e linkUpTrap   "Generate linkUp" ifOperStatus != 2
monitor  -r 1s -e linkDownTrap "Generate linkDown" ifOperS
```